# Bloomberg API - using .Net API to get the FUT_CHAIN on an underlying security

Tags: c#, .net, bloomberg

I am trying to query the Bloomberg API (.Net) to get the future chain on an underlying security. Preferably, I would be able to get the list of futures for a given date in the past.

The equivalent operation in Excel using the worksheet formula API would be the following:-

```
=BDS("ERA COMDTY","FUT_CHAIN","CHAIN_DATE=20120103",
    "INCLUDE_EXPIRED_CONTRACTS=Yes")
```

I looked at a large number of online resources, and I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Comment: Are you using the new Bloomberg API?  Not SAPI or Data License?  If you're using SAPI or Data License then the structures you're going to work with are going to be different.

Comment: @casperOne - I'm not sure, but I've now found a solution for this, and I will post up the code for it shortly.

Answer (score 5):

For the v3 API, you need to use request overrides.

```
Request request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");

request.append("securities", "ERA Comdty");

request.append("fields","FUT_CHAIN");

Element overrides = request.getElement("overrides");
Element override1 = overrides.appendElement();
override1.setElement("fieldId", "CHAIN_DATE");
override1.setElement("value", "20120103");
Element override2 = overrides.appendElement();
override2.setElement("fieldId", "INCLUDE_EXPIRED_CONTRACTS);
verride2.setElement("value", 'Y');

session.sendRequest(request);
```

Comment: The API behaves as if Bloomberg keeps a record of all available futures for each day in the past. The script above gives all commodities from the beginning to december 2017 (the last future traded at 20120103). You can also set include expired contracts to N, to get the active contracts at 20120103.