# how to fetch Future chain for a security using bloomberg DLWS

Tags: asp.net, bloomberg

We are using Bloomberg DLWS - Persecurity. I am trying to find a way to fetch the futures chain for a given security. I tried to find in the dlws documentation but could not find it. Does DLWS support this feature ? or should i be using API ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to ask the DL support team via help help whether this field is available in their field dictionary. Depending on what you want to do with the data and where you're working with it, the API could be a better way to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting here so that it helps someone. I contacted the BL team and we can fetch the futures chain. Need to search instrument by wildcard (macro) :

```
primaryQualifierType = SECTYP
primaryQualifierValue = "FUT_CHAIN"
secondaryQualifierType = SECURITY_DES
secondaryQualifierValue = "IBM US Equity"
```

A call to getdata will fetch all the contracts for ibm from all the exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be working on this at the moment. Forgive the code it's a bit rough but it does work. I am just looking at processing the results correctly but if you change the Log statements below to console.writeline or something similar you will see the chain. Hope it helps someone.

```
 Service refDataService = session.GetService("//blp/refdata");

        Request request = refDataService.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");
        Element securitieslElement = request.GetElement("securities");
        //securities.AppendValue("QEAA Comdty");
        securitieslElement.AppendValue("COA COMDTY");



        request.Append("fields", "FUT_CHAIN");

        Element overrides = request.GetElement("overrides");
        Element override1 = overrides.AppendElement();
        override1.SetElement("fieldId", "CHAIN_DATE");
        override1.SetElement("value", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        Element override2 = overrides.AppendElement();
        override2.SetElement("fieldId", "INCLUDE_EXPIRED_CONTRACTS");
        override2.SetElement("value", 'N');

        System.Console.WriteLine("Sending Request: " + request);
        session.SendRequest(request, null);

        while (true)
        {
            Event eventObj = session.NextEvent();
            if (eventObj.Type == Event.EventType.RESPONSE)
            {
                Log.Info("EventObj is type response - break.");
                break;
            }

            foreach (Message msg in eventObj)
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.Debug($"Processing message : {msg.AsElement}");

                    if (msg.HasElement(RESPONSE_ERROR))
                    {
                        WriteErrorInfo("REQUEST FAILED: ", msg.GetElement(RESPONSE_ERROR));
                        continue;
                    }

                    Element securities = msg.GetElement("securityData");
                    int numSecurities = securities.NumValues;
                    Log.Info("Processing " + numSecurities + " securities:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < numSecurities; ++i)
                    {
                        Element security = securities.GetValueAsElement(i);
                        string ticker = security.GetElementAsString(SECURITY);
                        Log.Info($"Ticker: {ticker}");

                        if (security.HasElement("securityError"))
                        {
                            WriteErrorInfo("\tSECURITY FAILED: ", security.GetElement(SECURITY_ERROR));
                            continue;
                        }

                        Log.Info("Processing fields");
                        Element fields = security.GetElement("fieldData");


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I should have also said I got this from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584483/bloomberg-api-using-net-api-to-get-the-fut-chain-on-an-underlying-security